# Define slide over screen width in runtime

Tags: ios, ipad, splitview

For my app's purposes I need to know all possible screen sizes when getting some content from internet. It's turned out to be hard to define screen widths for iPad Split View/Slide Over modes. F.e.: iPad Air 2 has 320px app's window width in slide over, but iPad Pro - 375px in the same mode. It's definitely not 33% of full width claimed by Apple. Thanks.